# Create a new object from the constructor of another object

Tags: javascript, oop

With a javascript object created from a class, how do create a new object using the same class without knowing what class created it.

For instance, the objects are stored in an array and new instances are to be created.

Deep copy using `structuredClone` or `Object.create()` do not seem to be what is needed.

Comment: See the linked question's answers and also [these](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+get+object%27s+constructor). **With caveats**, you can use the object's `constructor` property, but beware that not all objects are created via constructors, and sometimes (particularly before ES2015's `class` syntax was introduced) an object's `constructor` property may well *not* point to the function that constructed it.

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as a duplicated though, although it is related, it doesn't answer the question
you can do so by `new (instance.constructor)(params go here)`